# Updating a JTable with database query

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

The program I am working on contains two classes, GUI & DatabaseHelper. The table model used is DefaultTableModel.

The GUI contains consists of a simple JTable. It is initialised with data from the DatabaseHelper on startup. This works.

However, when trying to load new data into the table, it is not quite so straight forward.

My approach thus far has been:

```
model = DatabaseHelper.LoadData() // returns a default table model with new data.
tabel = new JTable();
tabel.setModel();
```

What happens now is that the loaded data is appended onto the already existing JTable.

If it is possible I would like to implement a solution using only the default table model. Thank you for any suggestions!

EDIT:

```
public void initGUI(){

        setJMenuBar(makeMenuBar()); 
        container   = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        model = db.initialiseTable();       // Load initialisation data from the database

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        scrollPane  = new JScrollPane(table);

        container.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        add(container);
    }
```

Returning a new model from database:

```
public DefaultTableModel loadData(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/version1", "root", "root");
            System.out.println("\nDatabase Connection Established.\n");

            String query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE test_number = 2";

            stmt        = con.createStatement();
            rs          = stmt.executeQuery( query );

            md          = rs.getMetaData();
            columns     = md.getColumnCount();  

            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <=columns-1; i++){
                row.addElement( rs.getObject(i+1) );
                }
                data.addElement( row );
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        columnNames.add(" ");
        columnNames.add("Column 1");
        columnNames.add("Column 2");

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

        return model;
    }
```

ActionPerformed, code handles new model returned from the DatabaseHelper

```
            model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model = db.loadData();

            table = new JTable();
            table.setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a bug in `DatabaseHelper.LoadData()`. For some reason, it doesn't create a new model but always returns the same model.

Create a new model in `DatabaseHelper.LoadData()` and it should work.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you for you suggestion.

The DatabaseHelper.LoadData() method was already returning a new datamodel. However your answer did give me an idea to create a new JTable, before adding the new model to it (code added in edit), which solves the issue of the extra table on the side. 

However, there is still the problem of loaded data being appeneded to the existing JTable, instead of simply displaying a table with only the loaded data.

Comment: The only way to append loaded to the existing JTable is by appending it to the existing table model! Java doesn't arbitrarily add data to existing tables or models; it's you're code which does this. I suggest you post the code how you create the table model so we can point out the mistake to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
model = DatabaseHelper.LoadData() // returns a default table model with new data.
tabel = new JTable();
tabel.setModel();
```

- there could be most important issue issue that you re_create `TableModel` and `JTable`, and this new `JTable` instance with `TableModel` isn't added to the `GUI`, don't do that, there no real reason to ...
- search of `ResulsetTableModel` (there you pass only `SQL Query`) or to use excelent code  [Table from Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) by `@camickr`

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you've got extra instantiations in the action handler:

```
        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model = db.loadData();

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model);
```

The `loadData` method instantiates a `DefaultTableModel` for you so you can skip the `new DefaultTableModel` and you already have a `JTable` from your `initGui` method so you should just reference that existing `Component`.

Now, it looks like you are only *adding* to the `columnNames` object. Perhaps you need to clear it or re-instantiate it each time through? If `loadData` will be called more than once it would be cleaner to create `columnNames` outside of the `loadData` method. Add " ", "Column 1" and "Column 2" there and only reference it inside `loadData`.